# Excel freezes after pasting text to a userform textbox

Tags: vba, textbox, freeze, userform

I have a vba userform text box with,

- ControlSource = An Excel Cell
- EnterKeyBehavior = True
- MultiLine = True
- MaxLength = 500

When I copy paste a text in the box such as a random text below:

*Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.*

and step away for this text box (by clicking somewhere else such an another text box),

- excel freezes (no response, cant open any excel file)
- CPU usage for excel gets to ~50% (exceptionally high compared to normal use)

Do you know the reason for this freeze/behaviour?

Code behind the user form:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_PD_NP_Click()
If Me.Tb_PD_1.Value = "" Or Me.Tb_PD_2.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please specify your Business Area and Activity Name.", vbExclamation, "Error!"
Exit Sub
End If
Unload Me
Uf2_Security.Show
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton_PD_PP_Click()
Unload Me
Uf1_Initiate.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Uf15_Project_Details
 .Height = 357
 .Left = 0
 .StartUpPosition = 2
 .Top = 0
 .Width = 480
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ControlSource = An excel cell

Comment: Any formula that depends from that ControlSource cell? Then this triggers a calculation of the formula and depending on the formula this calculation is running longer and freezes Excel while calculating. • The issue is probably not in the part you described but somewhere else.

Comment: Hi, In my case the Control Source cell is W!Q40 and it is used at 2 other places in the excel file. At both these places, it is used like this "=IF(W!Q40="","<Not Specified>",W!Q40)"

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, can this cause any issue?

Comment: Are any events for this text box in the code? Or any worksheet_change event in the sheet where the Control Source cell is?

Comment: No, there are no events defined for this text box or for the worksheet where it resides (W). W is a hidden sheet and so are the sheets where the formula "=IF(W!Q40="","<Not Specified>",W!Q40)" exists.

Comment: One more observation, I have been experimenting with different texts to see if it happens everytime. It seems if I type in a single row without using next line character (enter key), all works fine. However, as soon as I click on enter to go to next line, excel freezes. @PEH

Comment: OK, to find out if it has to do with the cells or the VBA code try the following: Remove the connection to the cell `ControlSource = `. Then paste again and see if it freezes or not. If it freezes the cell is the problem if not it can only be the code behind the userform.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ On removing the connection to the cell, all works fine (no freeze). Meaning the cell is the problem? How can that be?

Comment: Tried changing the [Control Source] to another cell (A2) in same worksheet, then to a different cell in another worksheet. The freeze issue comes back again, no matter what cell is chosen in the workbook.

Comment: Then it is probably something in the code of the userform. But we cannot help you without seeing that code.

Comment: Sure, added the code in the question itself. The name of the userform is "Uf15_Project_Details". It has 3 text boxes and 2 buttons viz. "Previous Page" (PP) and "Next Page" (NP)

Comment: Well somehow can't be the code, I'm out of ideas. Did you try it on another computer? Just to exclude that there is something wrong with that installation? It also could be a corrupted file. Can you reproduce the issue in a new file? Otherwise it would be very hard to track down the issue if you can't narrow it down a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas @Pᴇʜ. Tried it on other machines, its reproducible there as well. Also, when I replicated just this piece (the user form) in a new file, all works well. It must be something else (as its a big tool) and I am out of ideas as well.  
As a quick fix, changed the 'multi-line' and 'enter key behavior' properties of the text box to FALSE. This seems to fix the issue for now.  As a side-effect, it prevents user from copy-pasting paragraphs into the text box.
Will try other things in future, since ideally the user to be able to use multi line and enter key inside this text box.